# When a player first signed in using com.google.android.gms.plus

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

My current Android application allows users to signin using the Google Plus button.

A feature of my application is that i would like to reward users who return within a month of first signing in.

Do i have to remember when they first signed in using Google Plus?

Or does the `com.google.android.gms.plus` API expose this detail? e.g. initial Sign In date cross referenced to my Application.

I have searched the `com.google.android.gms.plus` docs but couldnt see anything.

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a G+ API that tells you when a user first authorized an application. I would recommend using [Androids app data storage](https://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html). That should be pretty lightweight. You can also [open a feature requests](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).

Comment: abraham, thanks for your time, i believe you are correct. i have raised a feature request.